# Speedtest-cli on a different interface

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have eth0, eth1 and wlan0 connected to my Raspberry Pi. I would like to measure the internet speed of the different interface, in this case - eth1. It works well for eth0 (192.168.1.21), but I get an error if I try to use a different interface, in this case, eth1 (192.168.8.100).

I have read Speedtest python API documentation and mostly copied code from there. I have also tried to search before posting on StackOverflow.

```
source = "192.168.8.100" #eth1
s = speedtest.Speedtest(source_address=source)
s.get_servers()
s.get_best_server()
s.download()
s.upload()
res = s.results.dict()
download = res["download"]
upload = res["upload"]
ping = round(res["ping"])
print(download, upload, ping)
```

EDIT: This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/root/post_test2.py", line 11, in home
    s = speedtest.Speedtest(source_address=source)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1091, in __init__
    self.get_config()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/speedtest.py", line 1123, in get_config
    raise ConfigRetrievalError(e)
speedtest.ConfigRetrievalError: <urlopen error timed out>
```

Comment: What is the error? Please paste the message, preferably with the complete stack trace.

Comment: Hi, I have added the error

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to speedtest-cli and this post has answered my question on how to use a different interface. So, thanks for that :-)

It's a bit of a guess, but your problem might be due to network routing.
Can you ping an external host through both interfaces:

```
ping -I eth0 google.com
ping -I eth1 google.com
```

If eth1 times out, then you probably need to update your network routing entries.

```
ip route
```